# YII - define extracted bootstrap in config file

Tags: yii

i'm new in Yii. and i'm using this [LINK](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html).

i'm extracted bootstrap on `/blog/protected/extensions` directory and define array into `config/main.php` like this:

```
    //BOOT STRAP
    'clientScript' => array(
        'scriptMap' => array(
        'jquery.js'=>false,
        'jquery.min.js'=>false,
        'core.css'=>false,
        'styles.css'=>false,
        'pager.css'=>false,
        'default.css'=>false,
        ),
        'packages'=>array(
        'jquery'=>array(
            'baseUrl'=>'bootstrap/',
            'js'=>array('js/jquery.js'=>true /* SET AS DEFAULT*/ ),
        ),          
        'bootstrap'=>array(
            'baseUrl'=>'bootstrap/',
            'js'=>array('js/bootstrap.min.js',
              'js/bootstrap-transition.js',
              'js/bootstrap-alert.js',
              'js/bootstrap-modal.js',
              'js/bootstrap-dropdown.js',
              'js/bootstrap-tab.js',
              'js/bootstrap-tooltip.js',
              'js/bootstrap-popover.js',
              'js/bootstrap-button.js',
              'js/bootstrap-collapse.js',
              'js/bootstrap-carousel.js',
              'js/bootstrap-typeahead.js',
              'js/bootstrap-affix.js',
              'js/holder.js',
              'js/prettify.js',
              'js/application.js',
             ),
            'css'=>array(
            'css/bootstrap.min.css',
            'css/custom.css',
            'css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css',
            ),
            'depends'=>array('jquery'),
        ),
        ),
    ),
    //BOOT STRAP
```

how to change `'baseUrl'=>'bootstrap/'` to correct path of extension? this path does not work:

```
'baseUrl'=>'/protected/extensions/bootstrap/',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new, [learn about extensions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.use).
Than download ready yii extension for bootstrap: [Yii-Bootstrap](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bootstrap/) or [Yii-Booster](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiibooster/).

You don't have to define any js package, bootstrap extension will do it for you.

Here is sample config part for yii-booster, which i use (actually for yii-bootstrap it should be same):

```
'components' => array(
// ... other components
    'bootstrap' => array(
        'class' => 'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
        'coreCss' => true,
        'responsiveCss' => true,
        'yiiCss' => true,
    ),
    ),
// .. other components
```

And thats it! Bootstrap will work.

Comment: thanks @PeterM. result: http://paste.debian.net/233498/  i get this error: `Alias "bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing directory or file.`

Comment: Right, there are a bit more to configure, i just have somewhat unusual setup. Check [sample config](http://cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/setup.html)

Comment: i'm coping bootstrap into theme directory from extension directory and change main.php to this link: http://paste.debian.net/233500/ and define `<?php Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap'); ?>
` into `views/layouts/main.php`. i get that error now. no correctly work :(

Comment: Youd didn't reed carefully, place `Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');` on top of config file, this is **crucial** to make it work. You should learn more about yii before messing with bootstrap, as it will only blur your understanding of framework.

Comment: thanks @PeterM. thats right. after setup `http://cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/` and put widget into `view/layouts/main.php` my page dont change with bootstrap css and js.